# Dockerfile ENV variables not being accepted

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I'm using docker and dockerfile to build images. I want to build a PostgreSQL image so I'm using this dockerfile:

```
ARG POSTGRES_USER=vetouz
ARG POSTGRES_PASSWORD=***
ARG POSTGRES_DB=vetouz_mediatheque

FROM postgres:latest

USER postgres

EXPOSE 5432
```

Then I run the image using this command

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=vetouz -d --name postgres postgres:latest
```

When I do that the role `vetouz`, the password and the db `vetouz_mediatheque` are not created and I don't understand why. I know it because when I access my container with `sudo docker exec -it postgres bash` and then run `psql -U vetouz` I get the error `role vetouz does not exist`.

It works if I run my image with the following command:

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*** -e POSTGRES_USER=vetouz -e POSTGRES_DB=vetouz_mediatheque -d --name postgres postgres:latest
```

But I would rather define my variables in the dockerfile.

Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 2):

Please use `ENV` instead of `ARG`. args are only available during build, envs are available during runtime as well.

**Source**

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

Answer (score 1):

### YOUR PROBLEM

As already stated your are using `ARG` that is only available when building the Docker image, but using `env` variables to set sensitive information in a Docker image is not a safe approach, and I will explain why.

### SECURITY CONCERNS

> But I would rather define my variables in the dockerfile.

This is ok for information that is not sensitive, but not a best practice for sensitive information like passwords, because the database credentials will be stored in plain text in the Dockerfile, and even if you use `ARG` to set the `ENV` var they will be available in the docker image layers.

> docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*** -e POSTGRES_USER=vetouz -e POSTGRES_DB=vetouz_mediatheque -d --name postgres postgres:latest

This is also a bad practice in terms of security because now your database credentials are saved into the bash history.

In a Linux machine you can check with:

```sh
history | grep -i POSTGRES
```

### A MORE SECURE APPROACH

Create an .env file:

```
POSTGRES_USER=vetouz
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=your-password-here
POSTGRES_DB=vetouz_mediatheque
```

Don't forget to add the `.env` file to `.gitignore`:

```sh
echo ".env" >> .gitignore
```

#### Running the Docker Container

Now run the docker container with:

```sh
docker run --env-file ./.env -d --name postgres postgres:latest
```